# Seed data from existing DB to a new DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm supposed to seed the partial data from existing Postgres DB residing on `Server A` into another Postgres DB residing on `Server B`. Is there any efficient way to do so apart from creating the API and executing in a Rake Task or using `seeds.rb`?

**More Details**

I tried the approach suggested by @Siim Liiser, but it creates the dump of all the data in the table instead of selected records. Is there any way to add a `where` clause in dump option?

Comment: Is this a one time thing or does it need to be done repeatedly? How big is the data? Answers to those would help me choose between `pg_dump`, api and `seeds.rb`

Comment: It's one time process on around 10 tables and 3k records in total.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pg_dump` to store data from `Server A` into a file. There's plenty of options to choose which partial data you want to export. Most useful is probably to specify which tables you want.

Move that file over to `Server B` (`scp` or whatever other tool you wish to use) and then `pg_restore` it into the database on `Server B`.

This is the best solution for a simple one time action in my opinion. Of course building an api for this would also work, but would be more work and slower to execute.

Comment: Are `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` the functions of `pgAdmin`? If yes, is it possible for `pgAdmin 4`?

Comment: Yes https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/backup_dialog.html

Comment: Thanks for the docs link. I'll check it out.